# The benefits of React-Native JavaScriptCore

Tags: javascript, react-native, v8

Definitely, all of us know about powerful `JavaScript` engine, So why in `React Native` is used a different engine that name is `JavaScriptCore`.

The JavaScriptCore does not support some `ES6` features like below function:

```
Array.prototype.flatten
```

What is benefits of JavaScriptCore to V8? Why the Facebook developers didn't use V8?

Comment: Cause it runs cross-platform?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

V8 does not run on iOS, because Apple does not allow third-party apps to generate code at runtime (a.k.a. "JIT-compiling"), which V8 heavily relies on for performance (*). JavaScriptCore, being made by Apple, is allowed to run (and JIT-compile code) on iOS. Since React Native's purpose is cross-platform development, this is a strong argument.

That said, `Array.prototype.flatten` is not an ES6 feature. It is currently a "[stage 3 proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-flatMap/)", meaning it will probably soon become an official part of JavaScript -- maybe ES2019 ("ES10" in the old naming scheme) or so. Also, it has been renamed to `Array.prototype.flat` due to web compatibility issues with the name `.flatten`. JavaScript engines have started to implement it; according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the latest version of Safari/JavaScriptCore already support it, so it's probably only a matter of time until support arrives in React Native too.

(*) There is an [ongoing effort](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=7777) to build a version of V8 that avoids all runtime code generation, trading a lot of performance for the ability to run anywhere, but it's not available yet.

Comment: JavaScriptCore on iOS does not use a JIT compiler in third-party apps, see the [page on JavaScript Environment](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment) in the Reactive Native docs.

Comment: JIT-less V8 Lite is available now. and already runs on IOS https://twitter.com/schuay/status/1105785897663057921